# Too many /_ah/warmup/ queries on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm getting multiple `/_ah/warmup/` requests per second to my Google App Engine instance.  I've disabled warmup requests so it's unclear why I'm getting any such requests.

A potential source of this error is that going to `/_ah/warmup/` results in an error, even though the endpoint is implemented (see [this file](https://github.com/mail-my-ballot/mail-my-ballot/blob/ab239529e34a3f1efdb338e165a2136a8a1d5b98/packages/server/src/index.ts)).  Compare the results at [/_ah/warmup](https://app-staging.mailmyballot.org/_ah/warmup) (implemented) with the results at [/_ah/warm](https://app-staging.mailmyballot.org/_ah/warm) (not implemented).

The `app.yaml` file (template) is available [here](https://github.com/mail-my-ballot/mail-my-ballot/blob/ab239529e34a3f1efdb338e165a2136a8a1d5b98/packages/server/app.tmpl.yaml).
Code available [here](https://github.com/mail-my-ballot/mail-my-ballot/tree/ab239529e34a3f1efdb338e165a2136a8a1d5b98/packages/server)

Using Google App Engine via Node 12.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those requests are still coming in from before you disabled them. They are looking to receive a valid response.

Notice the trailing slash for those incoming requests that fail?  Handle those as well. Your Express router is not `strict`, so it should handle them. But, handle them explicitly, and the error will go away, and the requests will stop.

You might want to explore packages like `express-slash` to handle different scenarios.