# How to stop warmup requests in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm getting warmup request every second in my GAE Python app, it results in 404, my app.yaml is below:

```
runtime: python37
entrypoint: gunicorn -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker api:app
instance_class: F4
inbound_services:
- warmup
handlers:
- url: /_ah/warmup
  script: auto
- url: /.*
  static_dir: /.*
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
  # ...
```

I've tried removing the `inbound_services: - warmup`, but the requests didn't stop, they also appear to be originated from an earlier version, any idea on how can I stop them?

similar issue: [Too many /_ah/warmup/ queries on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62476222/too-many-ah-warmup-queries-on-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about stopping them, I would think that removing `inbound_services: - warmup` would stop it.

As for your original issue of the 404s though, you need to setup a handler in your python code for the url `/_ah/warmup`, since you specified `script: auto`